# Unable to get all the sub projects using JitPack

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I am unable to load all the sub projects of this project: https://github.com/dankito/RichTextEditor
or the from the fork of same https://github.com/tangentq-admin/RichTextEditor

Ideally it should list:
RichTextEditorAndroid
RichTextEditorCommon
RichTextEditorJavaFX

But it loads only: RichTextEditorCommon and RichTextEditorJavaFX. **RichTextEditorAndroid is missing.**

URL: https://jitpack.io/#tangentq-admin/RichTextEditor/v2.0.15

I don't get what is missing in this subproject that it is not loading.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

no need JitPack

test it

```
buildscript { 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0" 
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I already have this but doesn't load the expected library. The question is more about `jitpack` not loading in their website too and not really on the android studio (though it doesn't load it in the android studio too). https://jitpack.io/#tangentq-admin/RichTextEditor/v2.0.15

Comment: can you send your  code to my email address? maybe i can help you